# How to utilize all processors in WSL?

Tags: cpu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, hyper-v

I am using HP Z6 G4 workstation. It has two processors each with 20 physical cores in it, but `lscpu` command on WSL only detects one processor. Due to that, I am not able to fully utilize all the physical cores of the system.

I am getting these `lscpu` results:
[image: lscpu]

I am expecting a code or steps to configure WSL so it can access all the processors in my workstation.

Comment: what is the content of `%USERPROFILE%\.wslconfig` (note: I'm assuming WSL2)

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The article
[Boost your WSL 2 performance using Microsoft instead of Intel CPU drivers](https://medium.com/twodigits/wsl-performance-using-intel-and-microsoft-drivers-f8aef9bf15dc)
describes the same problem :

> The Windows Resource Monitor shows only 50% load at full load of the WSL, with the standard driver from Microsoft for CPUs is at 100%.

The suggested solution is to disable the Intel drivers and force the
usage of the Microsoft ones.

This is done using `regedit`, at registry key
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\intelppm`
to set the value of the `Start` item to `4` (default is `3`),
then reboot.

As with all registry changes, take some precautions, at least creating
a System Restore point, so you could rollback Windows to its previous
state if a problem occurs.

Comment: Is there an alternative to AMD CPUs?

Comment: @TonyBogdanov: Better post a separate question with the details of your CPU. You may link to this post as an example of the recherched solution.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was I didn't have my config setup correctly. The registry change mentioned in the other post didn't do anything for me. i.e. in C:/Users/<*username*>/.wslconfig

```
[wsl2]
processors=8
```

This should be set to the number logical processors, not the number of physical cores. Make sure you restart WSL after updating.

If you run this before and after the change you should see a difference.

```
lscpu | grep -E "CPU\(s):|Thread|Core\(s|Socket"
sysbench cpu --threads=$(nproc) run
```

Also see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#configure-global-options-with-wslconfig